# Split dataframe into distinct multiple groups using two columns, then do PCA on each group and Plot the PCA figures

Tags: python, r

I want to do the following

1. split a dataset based on two unique columns `make` and `model`.
2. export each resulting data frame into a `.csv` file with the unique make and model as file name - `make_model`.csv.
3. for each csv file, I want to do a PCA using numeric columns-`mileage`, `lease` ,`mpg`
4. scatterplot for each PCA with each plot having the name of the csv_file, example- `honda_accord`
5. place 4 figures per page  and export as pdf files

```
'df'
   make, model, year, mileage, lease, mpg, target
1   toyota, corolla, 2015, 17510, 710, 20,Y
2   honda, accord, 2012, 73640, 723, 23,Y
3   toyota, corolla, 2020 28525, 610,24, N
4   kia, sportage, 2018, 31008, 592, 20, N
5   volkswagen, jetta, 2017, 18007, 599,21, Y
6   honda, accord, 2017, 18850, 690, 23,N
7   volkswagen, jetta 2012, 5065, 292, 21, N
8   toyota, highlander,2019, 18004, 729,18, Y
9   volkswagen, jetta, 2016, 8361, 692,21, Y
10  toyota,highlander, 2021, 28643, 729,18, Y
```

Desired outcome:

```
# csv_name: toyota_corolla.csv
1   toyota, corolla, 2015, 17510, 710,20, Y
3   toyota, corolla, 2020 28525, 610,24, N

# csv_name: toyota_landcruiser.csv
8   toyota, highlander,2019, 18004, 729,18, Y
10  toyota,highlander, 2021, 28643, 729, 18, Y

#csv_name: honda_accord.csv
2   honda, accord, 2012, 73640, 723, 23, Y
6   honda, accord, 2017, 18850, 690, 23, N

#csv_name: volkswagen_jetta.csv 
5  volkswagen, jetta 2012, 5065, 292, 21, N
7  volkswagen, jetta, 2017, 18007, 599,21, Y
9  volkswagen, jetta, 2016, 8361, 692,21, N
```

See below for my code

in R

```
# 1. split a dataset based on two unique columns `make` and `model`.
df %>%
  select(everything()) %>%
  group_split(make,model) -> split_data 

#2:  export each resulting data frame into a .csv file with the unique make and model as file name - make_model.csv.looping through the list of dataframes

for (i in seq_along(split_data)) {
    filename = paste(i, ".csv") 
    write.csv(data[[i]], filename) # returns only numbers '1.csv' instead of 'make_model.csv'
}

# 3 : for each csv file, I want to do a PCA using numeric columns-`mileage`, `lease` ,`mpg` 

library(dplyr)
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csvr (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
 
temp.pca <- prcomp(temp[,4:6])

# 4. scatterplot for each PCA with each plot having the name of the csv_file, example- honda_accord
library(ggfortify)
pca.plot <- autoplot(temp.pca, data = pilots, colour = 'target') # use the target Y and N as colors preferably Y-> green and N-> red
pca.plot

# 5. place four figures per page  and export as pdf files  
par(mfrow=c(2,2)) 
ggsave('cars_scatterplot.pdf')
```

In Python

```
#1. split a dataset based on two unique columns make and model. 
#2. export each resulting data frame into a .csv file with the unique make and model as file name - make_model.csv.

for i in df.groupby(["make", "model"])[["make", "model"]].apply(lambda x: list(np.unique(x))):
    df.groupby(["make", "model"]).get_group((i[1], i[0])).to_csv(f"{i[1]}_{i[0]}.csv")  # for some reason, this does not return all the unique files .csv files
 
# 3, 4 & 5

import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2,figsize=(9,6))
for ax,file in zip(axs.flatten(), glob.glob("./*csv")):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df_temp = df.iloc[:,3:5]
    make = df['make'][0]
    model= df['model'][0] 
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaler.fit(df_temp)
    scaled_data = scaler.transform(df_temp)
    pca = PCA(n_components=2)
    pca.fit(scaled_data)
    x_pca = pca.transform(scaled_data)
    ax.scatter(x_pca[:,0],x_pca[:,1],c = colormap[target])  # color "red' and 'green' preferred
    ax.set_title(f"make:{make}, model:{model}")
    ax.set_xlabel('First principal component')
    ax.set_ylabel('Second Principal Component')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.legend() 
fig.savefig("car_scatterplot.pdf",dpi = 300)
```

Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code looks quite good. I have changed only some minor things to the python code and got it running.

First, I was creating the data manually so we could reproduce the behavior.

```
# create data manually to be able to reproduce the scenario
cols =  ["make", "model", "year", "mileage", "lease", "mpg", "target"]
rows =  [["toyota", "corolla", 2015, 17510, 710, 20, "Y"],
    ["honda", "accord", 2012, 73640, 723, 23, "Y"],
    ["toyota", "corolla", 2020, 28525, 610,24, "N"],
    ["volkswagen", "jetta", 2017, 18007, 599, 21, "Y"],
    ["honda", "accord", 2017, 18850, 690, 23, "N"],
    ["volkswagen", "jetta", 2012, 5065, 292, 21, "N"],
    ["toyota", "highlander", 2019, 18004, 729, 18, "Y"],
    ["volkswagen", "jetta", 2016, 8361, 692,21, "Y"],
    ["toyota", "highlander", 2021, 28643, 729,18, "Y"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, data=rows)
```

As you might notice, I removed the Kia here. This is because we need a minimum of two points for a PCA with `n_components=2`.

As your approach for the splitting did not work for me either, I just implemented a quite simple solution.

```
# 1
groups = df.groupby(["make", "model"]).count().index
```

Then we can make #2 similar than you already do.

```
# 2
for group in groups:
    df[(df["make"] == group[0]) & (df["model"] == group[1])].to_csv(f"{group[0]}_{group[1]}.csv")
```

#3 - #5 were basically fine, just keep in mind that the end index is excluded not included, so will have to write:

```
df_temp = df.iloc[:,3:6]
```

I have also defined a colormap, so steps 3-5 look like this:

```
colormap = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green']

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2,figsize=(9,6))
for ax,file in zip(axs.flatten(), glob.glob("./*csv")):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df_temp = df.iloc[:,3:6]
    make = df['make'][0]
    model= df['model'][0] 
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaler.fit(df_temp)
    scaled_data = scaler.transform(df_temp)
    pca = PCA(n_components=2)
    pca.fit(scaled_data)
    x_pca = pca.transform(scaled_data)
    ax.scatter(x_pca[:,0],x_pca[:,1], c = colormap[:len(x_pca)])  # color "red' and 'green' preferred
    ax.set_title(f"make:{make}, model:{model}")
    ax.set_xlabel('First principal component')
    ax.set_ylabel('Second Principal Component')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.legend() 
fig.savefig("car_scatterplot.pdf",dpi = 300)
```

Edit:

To implement a multipage pdf, I have extended the data to the following:

```
# create data manually to be able to reproduce the scenario
cols =  ["make", "model", "year", "mileage", "lease", "mpg", "target"]
rows =  [["toyota", "corolla", 2015, 17510, 710, 20, "Y"],
    ["honda", "accord", 2012, 73640, 723, 23, "Y"],
    ["toyota", "corolla", 2020, 28525, 610,24, "N"],
    ["volkswagen", "jetta", 2017, 18007, 599, 21, "Y"],
    ["honda", "accord", 2017, 18850, 690, 23, "N"],
    ["volkswagen", "jetta", 2012, 5065, 292, 21, "N"],
    ["toyota", "highlander", 2019, 18004, 729, 18, "Y"],
    ["volkswagen", "jetta", 2016, 8361, 692,21, "Y"],
    ["toyota", "highlander", 2021, 28643, 729,18, "Y"],
    ["bmw", "M5", 2005,84392, 649, 25, "Y"],
    ["bmw", "M5", 2012, 17499, 899, 20, "N"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, data=rows)
df["color"] = df.apply(lambda row: "green" if row["target"] == "Y" else "red", axis=1)
```

You will have to add the following imports.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import os
```

Then, for 3, 4 and 5, we can do the following that also generates the legends now.

```
# 3 4 5
files = [x for x in os.listdir("./") if os.path.splitext(x)[1] == ".csv"]
with PdfPages('car_scatterplot.pdf') as pdf:
    for i in range(0, len(files), 4):
        fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2,figsize=(9,6))
        max_len = i + 4 if len(files) > i + 4 else len(files)
        for ax, file in zip(axs.flatten(), files[i:max_len]):
            df = pd.read_csv(file)
            df_temp = df.iloc[:,3:6]
            make = df['make'][0]
            model= df['model'][0] 
            scaler = StandardScaler()
            scaler.fit(df_temp)
            scaled_data = scaler.transform(df_temp)
            pca = PCA(n_components=2)
            pca.fit(scaled_data)
            x_pca = pca.transform(scaled_data)
            df["x_pca_1"] = x_pca[:,0]
            df["x_pca_2"] = x_pca[:,1]
            for target in ["Y", "N"]:
                sub_df = df[df["target"] == target]
                if len(sub_df) > 0:
                    ax.scatter(sub_df["x_pca_1"],sub_df["x_pca_2"] ,c = sub_df['color'], label=target)  # color "red' and 'green' preferred
            ax.set_title(f"make:{make}, model:{model}")
            ax.set_xlabel('First principal component')
            ax.set_ylabel('Second Principal Component')
            plt.tight_layout()
            ax.legend(loc='best') 
        pdf.savefig(fig, dpi = 300)
```

The output then looks like this.
[image]

Comment: 1& 2 works perfect!. 3,4 & 5, the plot only returned the first 4 plots on one page. I was thinking of getting 4 plots per pdf page (Ex: Page 1 should have four figures. Page 2: another set of four  figures.. ,Page n: last set of make_model. Likewise, I included `c =df['target']`  in the scatterplot, looks like this -  `ax.scatter(x_pca[:,0],x_pca[:,1],c = df['target'],cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ['red',"green"])`, Also, the legend is not empty `plt.legend()`,I will like the legend to show` Y: Green, N: red` colors from the `target` column

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have added the multipage and the legend functionality. I hope it's fine now.

Comment: You are the real MVP! Thanks a million. Have a great weekend!